# How to avoid shared memory leaks

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I'm using shared memory between 2 processes on Suse Linux and I'm wondering how can I avoid the shared memory leaks in case one process crashes or both. Does a leak occur in this case? If yes, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Use a shared `mmap()` mapping of a file instead?

Comment: Because when a process dies all it's mapped memory regions go away too, unlike with shared memory segments that can get orphaned. Of course, in this case the file is still there if the process dies unexpectedly, but it's no longer mapped in memory consuming memory resources...

Answer (score 1):

You could allocate space for two counters in the shared memory region: one for each process.  Every few seconds, each process increments its counter, and checks that the other counter has been incremented as well.  That makes it easy for these two processes, or an external watchdog, to tear down the shared memory if somebody crashes or exits.

Answer (score 1):

- If the subprocess is a simple `fork()` from the parent process, then `mmap()` with `MAP_SHARED` should work.
- If the subprocess does an `exec()` to start a different executable, you can often pass file descriptors from `shm_open()` or a similar non-portable system call (see [Is there anything like shm_open() without filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55704758/6272277)) On many operating systems, including Linux, you can `shm_unlink()` the file descriptor from `shm_open()` so it doesn't leak memory when your processes die, and use `fcntl()` to clear the close-on-exec flag on the shm file descriptor so that your child process can inherit it across exec. This is not well defined in the POSIX standard but it appears to be very portable in practice.
- If you need to use a filename instead of just a file descriptor number to pass the shared memory object to an unrelated process, then you have to figure out some way to `shm_unlink()` the file yourself when it's no longer needed; see John Zwinck's answer for one method.