# Is there anything like shm_open() without filename?

Tags: unix, posix, shared-memory

The POSIX `shm_open()` function returns a file descriptor that can be used to access shared memory. This is extremely convenient because one can use all the traditional mechanisms for controlling file descriptors to also control shared memory.

The only drawback is that `shm_open()` always wants a filename. So I need to do this:

```c
// Open with a clever temp file name and hope for the best.
fd = shm_open(tempfilename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600);

// Immediately delete the temp file to keep the shm namespace clean.
shm_unlink(tempfilename);

// Then keep using fd -- the shm object remains as long as there are open fds.
```

This use of `tempfilename` is difficult to do portably and reliably. The interpretation of the filename (what the namespace is, how permissions are handled) differs among systems.

In many situations the processes using the shared memory object have no need for a filename because the object can be accessed more simply and safely by just passing a file descriptor from one process to another. So is there something that's just like `shm_open()` but can be used without touching the shared memory filename namespace?

`mmap()` with `MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED` is great but instead of a file descriptor it gives a pointer. The pointer doesn't survive over an exec boundary and can't be sent to another process over a Unix domain socket like file descriptors can.

The file descriptor returned by `shm_open()` also doesn't survive an exec boundary by default: the POSIX definition says that *the FD_CLOEXEC file descriptor flag associated with the new file descriptor is set.* But it is possible to clear the flag using `fcntl()` on MacOS, Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFlyBSD and possibly other operating systems.

Comment: Why the downvote - what is wrong with this question?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### A library to solve the problem

I managed to write [a library](https://github.com/lassik/shm_open_anon) that provides the simple interface:

```
int shm_open_anon(void);
```

The library compiles without warnings and successfully runs a test program on Linux, Solaris, MacOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFlyBSD and Haiku. You may be able to adapt it to other operating systems; please send a pull request if you do.

The library returns a file descriptor with the close-on-exec flag set. You can clear that flag using `fcntl()` on all supported operating systems, which will allow you to pass the fd over `exec()`. The test program demonstrates that this works.

### Implementation techniques used in the library

The readme of the library has very precise notes on what was done and what wasn't done for each OS. Here's a summary of the main stuff.

There are several non-portable things that are more or less equivalent to `shm_open()` without a filename:

- FreeBSD can take `SHM_ANON` as the pathname for [`shm_open()`](http://man.openbsd.org/shm_mkstemp) since 2008.
- Linux has a [`memfd_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) system call since kernel version 3.17.
- Earlier versions of Linux can use `mkostemp(name, O_CLOEXEC | O_TMPFILE)` where `name` is something like `/dev/shm/XXXXXX`. Note that we are not using `shm_open()` at all here -- `mkostemp()` is implicitly using a perfectly ordinary `open()` call. Linux mounts a special memory-backed file system in `/dev/shm` but some distros use `/run/shm` instead so there are pitfalls here. And you still have to shm_unlink() the temp file.
- OpenBSD has a [`shm_mkstemp()`](http://man.openbsd.org/shm_mkstemp) call since release 5.4. You still have to `shm_unlink()` the temp file but at least it is easy to create safely.

For other OSes, I did the following:

1. Figure out an OS-dependent format for the *name* argument of POSIX `shm_open()`. Please note that there is no name you can pass that is absolutely portable. For example, NetBSD and DragonFlyBSD have conflicting demands about slashes in the name. This applies even if your goal is to use a named shm object (for which the POSIX API was designed) instead of an anonymous one (as we are doing here).
2. Append some random letters and numbers to the name (by reading from `/dev/random`). This is basically what `mktemp()` does, except we don't check whether our random name exists in the file system. The interpretation of the *name* argument varies wildly so there's no reasonable way to portably map it to an actual filename. Also Solaris doesn't always provide `mktemp()`. For all practical purposes, the randomness we put in will ensure a unique name for the fraction of a second that we need it.
3. Open the shm object with that name via `shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_NOFOLLOW, 0600)`. In the astronomical chance that our random filename already exists, `O_EXCL` will cause this call to fail anyway, so no harm done. The `0600` permissions (owner read-write) are necessary on some systems instead of blank `0` permissions.
4. Immediately call `shm_unlink()` to get rid of the random name. The file descriptor remains for our use.

This technique is not quaranteed to work by POSIX, but:

1. The `shm_open()` *name* argument is underspecified by POSIX so nothing else is guaranteed to work either.
2. I'll let the above compatibility list speak for itself.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. Since both System V shared memory model and POSIX shared file mapping for IPC require operations with a file, there is always need for a file in order to do mapping.

> `mmap()` with `MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED` is great but instead of a file
>   descriptor it gives a pointer. The pointer doesn't survive over an
>   exec boundary and can't be sent to another process over a Unix domain
>   socket like file descriptors can.

As [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) says,

> Neither memory mappings created via `mmap()` nor POSIX shared-memory
>   segments obtained via `shm_open()` nor System V shared-memory segments
>   obtained via `shmat()` are preserved across an `exec`.

There must be a well-known place on the memory to meet and exchange information. That's why a file is the requirement. By doing this, after `exec`, the child is able to reconnect to the appropriate shared memory.

Comment: It's possible to clear the close-on-exec flag on the file descriptor returned by `shm_open()` to preserve that fd over an exec boundary. This is probably not guaranteed to work by POSIX but I wrote a test program to try it and it worked fine on MacOS, Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFlyBSD.

Comment: @Lassi There may not be always the best of luck to you. Rule of thumb, always abide by standards at least for portability.

Comment: I agree in general, but in cases like this a not-fully-standard solution is very widely supported and the fully-standard solution is substantially more complicated. (Any use of a tempfile raises questions about race conditions, name clashes and who cleans it up on error.) E.g. in this case, if the close-on-exec thing is not supported on some Unix, I would try to contact the people making that Unix to ask if they could add it. I realize this isn't always an option but it's the first thing I would try.

Comment: I just found out that there is nothing you can pass as the filename to `shm_open()` that works on all operating systems. NetBSD wants exactly one slash; DragonFlyBSD fails if you give only one slash. So the POSIX API is a standard in name only.

Answer (score 1):

> This use of `tempfilename` is difficult to do portably and reliably. The interpretation of the filename (what the namespace is, how permissions are handled) differs among systems.

You can have [`mkstemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) create a unique filename in `/dev/shm/` or `/tmp` and open the file for you. You can then `unlink` the filename, so that no other process can open this file, apart from the process that have the file descriptor returned from `mkstemp`.

> `mkstemp()`: CONFORMING TO 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: `/dev/shm` seems like a Linux-only thing. `/tmp` may be universal (at least for now) but I find it kind of iffy to use a global directory for all users. Using the root directory, e.g. `/$PID`, doesn't work on DragonFlyBSD since shm perms work the same way as normal file perms. `$HOME/.shm-$PID` might be the least objectionable choice :) Also OpenBSD gives a linker warning when you link a program using `mktemp()` because many people don't guard against the race condition it creates (in this case you can do so by giving `O_EXCL` to `shm_open()`). But the linker warning doesn't look nice.

Comment: @Lassi Are you sure the linker warns about `mkstemp`, not `mktemp`? _there is a race between testing whether the name exists and opening the file, every use of `mktemp()` is a security risk.  The race is avoided by `mkstemp(3)` and `mkdtemp(3)`._

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, the warning is about `mktemp()`. `mkstemp()` doesn't produce a linker warning but it creates a regular file and opens a file descriptor to it. The thing is, `shm_open()` wants to get a filename and open its own file descriptor (which I presume is a special kind of fd for a shared memory object, not a regular file). Did you manage to find a shm function that can take the fd from `mkstemp()`?

Comment: @Lassi `shm_open` returns a regular file `fd`. _The POSIX shared memory object implementation on Linux makes use of a dedicated `tmpfs(5)` filesystem that is normally mounted under `/dev/shm`._

Comment: OK, that's cool. But `/dev/shm` appears Linux-only, I can't find it on any BSD. However! OpenBSD has a `shm_mkstemp()` function just for this job, and FreeBSD's `shm_open()` can take `SHM_ANON` as the path argument. You learn something new every day :)

Comment: Also here's a great blog post summarizing all this stuff: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/04/10/ ("Mapping Multiple Memory Views in User Space")

Comment: Also note that some Linux distros don't mount the temp filesystem in `/dev/shm`. Notably recent Debian releases mount it in `/run/shm`. The nice thing about standards is there are so many to choose from...

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating it with access rights to 0?
Thus no process would be able to "open" it and let you unlink it safely just after?

Comment: That doesn't work on MacOS. Maybe it works on Linux? I recall some talk about applying the permissions only after the file has been created, in which case the creator of the file could keep writing to the fd it got even though others can't. But MacOS just gives me "bad file descriptor" when I try that. 0600 permissions work fine.

Comment: @Lassi Didn't know that, I remember that posix require that access rights do not play any role when creating the file and requesting any access; this may work only for ordinary files...

Comment: That's interesting. In what directory did you create it? I tried generating a name with `/tmp/shmXXXXXXX` using `mktemp()` and giving the results to `shm_open()`. It works if I'm root but otherwise I get `Permission denied`. I forget where I got `Bad file descriptor` earlier but that was probably a mistake in my code back then.

Comment: Note that using mktmp is not great as the name may race before the object is opened.